# Проблема с обновлением recycler view

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Проблема такая: есть у меня адаптер для `recycler view`, два метода из него:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(mTodoItems.get(position).isChecked());
    holder.mEditText.setText(mTodoItems.get(position).getString());
    holder.mRemoveImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v){
            mTodoItems.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
            mTodoItems.get(position).setChecked(isChecked);
        }
    });
    holder.mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){

        }

        @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

        }

        @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
            mTodoItems.get(position).setString(s.toString());
        }
    });
}

public void addItem(TodoItem todoItem){
    mTodoItems.add(todoItem);
    notifyItemInserted(mTodoItems.size()-1);
}
```

Если элементов меньше 6, то, вроде бы, всё нормально, иначе вылетает IndexOutOfBoundsException. Сколько уже пытаюсь найти проблему, всё никак не получается. Может сталкивался кто с таким?

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kapmayn.artyom.kitchen, PID: 27129
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.kapmayn.artyom.kitchen.adapters.TodoListRecyclerAdapter$3.afterTextChanged(TodoListRecyclerAdapter.java:61)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8004)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4356)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4204)
at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:84)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4179)
at com.kapmayn.artyom.kitchen.adapters.TodoListRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TodoListRecyclerAdapter.java:39)
at com.kapmayn.artyom.kitchen.adapters.TodoListRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TodoListRecyclerAdapter.java:22)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18796)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18796)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18796)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18796)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1107)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:631)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18796)`

Comment: стек-трейс бы не помешал.

Comment: это то, что нужно было?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

holder.mEditText.addTextChangedListener - вот беда. На момент создания - position отображает текущее состояние, но если этот элемент последний, а предыдущий был удалён, то индекс последнего элемента уже position-1, а обращение  mTodoItems.get(position).setString(s.toString()); выбросит ошибку.

Comment: та же фигня с holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener.
Сохраняйте в холдере ссылку на сам элемент mTodoItems.get(position) и оперируйте им и будет вам счастье.

Comment: спасибо, так и поступлю

Answer (score 0):

Где то в коде у вас фигурирует `ArrayList`, который в приведенном выше куске отсутствует.

По стектрейсу видно, что в вашем листе вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу бОльшему, чем есть в листе, откуда эксепшн, вот эта строка из трейса говорит наглядно:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5
```

Не допустимый индекс 5, размер 5. То есть вы можете обратиться по индексу от 0 до 4, но не к 5 и больше.

Comment: это я прекрасно понимаю,
написал же, что если элементов меньше 6, то такого эксепшена нет